# NetLogo Trouble detecting turtles in radius

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to have a car visit 50 different cities in the shortest route possible, and every time he visits a place he changes the colour of the city form blue to yellow and moves on, trouble is I'm finding errors trying to find a way to implement this. I'm getting many errors in the last line of code, where it says CAR expected 1 input, a number. Any help would be appreciated.

```
breed [cities city]
breed [cars car]

cars-own [history travelled-distance]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
end

to setup-turtles
  ask n-of 50 patches with [pcolor = 55 and not any? other turtles-here][sprout-cities 1 [set color blue set size 2 set shape "square"]]

   create-cars 1[
    setxy -90 -90
    set color red
    set size 5
  ]
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor green]
  ask n-of 100 patches [set pcolor brown ask neighbors [set pcolor brown]]
end

to go
    ask cars [
    pendown
    if history <= 50  
    [   ;set heading towards city in-radius 10]]
      move-to min-one-of cities in-radius 360 [distance myself] 
    ]
      if car in-radius 5 = true [set color = yellow]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

set heading towards one-of cities in-radius 10

Comment: Thanks for commenting but trying this, I got a runtime error https://prnt.sc/11ek5g5

Comment: I don't understand why you care to set the heading anyway since the next thing you do is move somewhere different.   In any case yes, if you want to set the heading, you need to pick a city to head towards that is (a) within radius 10 and also (b) NOT on the same patch you're on -- although that still leaves a choice of WHICH of MULTIPLE hits you want to select.